What's the deal with this comparator's hysteresis?
I have here a circuit designed by someone else to create a 50% duty cycle square wave that leads a current transformer in phase. The CT maxes out at about 1 amp, and the output of the phase-leading and squaring off of the CT's sinusoidal waveform is connected to the negative input of the TLV3501 comparator shown. The positive input is supposedly just V/2 with hysteresis, and the aforementioned waveform gets conveniently centered around V/2 due to the AC coupling capacitor C5 and the feedback provided by R21 and R25, meaning a zero crossing detector is created.

The question: why does the positive input of the comparator effectively have second-order feedback as a hysteresis network? What's the point of R26 and C33 being there? All examples of comparator hysteresis I've seen online only include one resistor; this would be R7. Here's an example of a Texas Instruments application note that shows a very similar setup. In my simulations in LTspice, I found that C33 actually caused huge RC-shaped disturbances at the positive input. While this didn't seem to affect the intended operation too much in the sim, it certainly did not look pleasing and sometimes even went well outside the comparator's absolute maximum rating.
A second question: why is R25, and thus the feedback resistance on the negative input, adjustable? This doesn't seem like a useful feature to me, and I found that the best-looking waveforms in LTspice were when the total resistance was at its highest.
All interpretations are appreciated. Thanks.

Is the network formed by C32, R3, R8, L1 and R1 the burden of the CT?

@RohatKılıç Yes, effectively a burden. Not entirely sure how it works yet though.
